# How do I shop tkPDFViewer from combining PDF's when opening PDFs using buttons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, tkinter

In this code, I'm trying to open PDFs as a separate window using tkinter and tkPDFViewer. The way this is done is a simple UI opens up with 2 buttons for 2 articles that are accessed from my computer in this case (but I just labeled it "filepath" for the file path to avoid revealing personal info). However, while the buttons work and open up a PDF window and a download window below that (as expected), when you close the PDF window (and the download window closes along with it) and then re-click on a button (the same one or a different one), it shows the previous pdf and the current one that appeared when you re-click combined. As you repeat this process, the PDFs just append to each other. However, what should happen is that the corresponding PDF to the article that is described in the button is shown and no other PDFs. How do I fix this? I've already tried to move the PDF initialization outside the event function then re-initialize it, but that results in a "local variable used before being defined" error, so that doesn't work, and I currently do not know of any other way to do this.

```
pdfArray = [
    ["skweak: Weak Supervision Made Easy for NLP",
    r"filepath", 
    "Pierre Lison, Jeremy Barnes, and Aliaksandr Hubin",
    "skweak, NLP, Natural Language Processing"],
    
    ["Information Theoretic-Based Quality Measures for Clustering",
    r"filepath",
    "Barry Drake, and Tiffany Huang",
    "Quality Measures, Clustering, Data"
    ]
]

#Import tkinter library
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkPDFViewer import tkPDFViewer as pdfViewer
from functools import partial
import shutil

#Create an instance of tkinter frame or window
mainWin= Tk()

#Set the geometry of tkinter frame
mainWin.geometry("1000x600+20+20")
download_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'filepath')
paw_icon = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'filepath')

def download_pdf(original_file):
    #this if-else statment detects if the original file exists.
    if os.path.isfile(original_file):
        newFileStem = os.path.expanduser('~') + r"\Downloads\ChatBox_download"
        num = 0
        while os.path.isfile(newFileStem + "(%d).pdf"%num):
           num = num + 1;

        newFile = newFileStem + "(%d).pdf"%num

        f = open(newFile, "x")
        shutil.copyfile(original_file, newFile)


        completeWin = Toplevel(mainWin)
        completeWin.geometry("400x75+660+480")
        completeWin.title("Download Complete")
        Label(completeWin, text = "Download Complete!", font = ('Gabriola', 14, 'bold')).pack()
        Label(completeWin, text = str(newFile), font = ('Gabriola', 10)).pack(pady=2)
        
    else:
        notFoundWin = Toplevel(mainWin)
        notFoundWin.geometry("200x75+660+480")
        notFoundWin.title("File Not Found")
        Label(notFoundWin, text = "File Not Found", font = ('Gabriola', 14, 'bold')).pack(pady=20)


#Define a new function to open the window
def open_win(pdf_ID):
   pdf_title = pdfArray[pdf_ID][0] #title of pdf
   file_location = pdfArray[pdf_ID][1] #location of pdf
   authors = pdfArray[pdf_ID][2] #authors
   keywords = pdfArray[pdf_ID][3] #keywords
    
   pdfWin = Toplevel(mainWin)
   pdfWin.geometry("600x350+640+20")
   pdfWin.title(pdf_title)

   # Adding pdf location and width and height.

   pdfViewer.ShowPdf().pdf_view(pdfWin, pdf_location=file_location, width=70, height=100).pack(ipadx = 10, ipady = 10)

   infoWin = Toplevel(pdfWin)
   infoWin.geometry("600x200+640+420")
   infoWin.title("PDF Information")
   
   Label(infoWin, text = "Information: ", font = ('Gabriola', 15, 'bold')).pack(pady=2)
   Label(infoWin, text = "Title: " + pdf_title, font = ('Gabriola', 12)).pack(pady=1) 
   Label(infoWin, text = "Author(s): " + authors, font = ('Gabriola', 12)).pack(pady=1)
   Label(infoWin, text = "Keyword(s): " + keywords, font = ('Gabriola', 12)).pack(pady=1)
   tk.Button(infoWin, image=download_icon, borderwidth = 0, command=partial(download_pdf, file_location)).pack(pady=1)

    
#Create a label
Label(mainWin, text= "Click any button below to open a PDF", font= ('Gabriola', 25, 'bold')).pack(pady=30, padx = 10)

#Create a button to open a New Window
for ID in range(0, len(pdfArray)):
    tk.Button(mainWin, image=paw_icon, compound=LEFT, text="  Open \" " + pdfArray[ID][0]+" \"", font= ('Gabriola', 12), command=partial(open_win, ID)).pack(pady=2)
    
mainWin.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well when using tkPDFViewer.
To fix I had to go into the tkPDFViewer module and add a line:

```
self.img_object_li.clear()
```

immediately after the line:

```
    def add_img():
```

I'm just a beginner myself so this was my fix to get around the issue.
From what I understand the line:

```
        self.img_object_li.append(timg)
```

adds images indefinitely, I was trying to destroy the frame and widgets containing the objects from my main program but couldn't get it to work at all. Issue just kept persisting. This is probably not the best way to do it and someone else will ahve a better fix.

Comment: Superb Answer ! Thank You very much. I'm not the original author of the question but this answer helped me a lot. Thanks !